# Is there a utility in python which I can use to save excel files in html format without loosing style of cells.?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

How can we save .xls and .xlsx files as html?

I tried with pandas like below -

```
wb_path = r"C:/Users/Anoop/sample.xlsx"
myfile = r"C:/Users/Anoop/sample.html"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(wb_path)
html = df.to_html()
open(myfile, 'w').write(html)
```

But the generated "sample.html" doesn't have color coding and styles of source excel intact.

Is there a way I can save excel data with style in .html using python ? 
My development environment is redhat linux.

Comment: why is this a python question? this can be solved by any converter found with a simple web-search!

Comment: @Marcel Zoll

Because I have an existing python script which does several other things. I need do  "Save Excel As HTML"  for few .xls and .xlsx also by the same script.

Thanks.